# Is "Room of lies" a Star Wars reference?

Tags: star-wars

The phrase "Room of Lies" in the ad [Star Wars Kraft Macaroni & Cheese "Can't Play"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7roF7YNzAgs) a reference to a phrase in the Star Wars franchise?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHpKxdbkcGc

Comment: No, it's just a reference to the fact that the room has toys you can't play with and food you can't eat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it's hard to prove a negative, there don't seem to be any references to a "*room of lies*" in any of the Star Wars scripts, novelisations, EU novels or supplementary media that I have access to.

There's a glancing reference to the phrase in an earlier novel by Brian Aldiss, the 1983 "[Helliconia Summer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helliconia)" that the advert writer may have been referencing, either consciously or unconsciously:

> *'The verdict is as follows. The hand that committed this vile murder
>   belongs to the son. The mind that controlled the hand is the father's.
>   So where lies the source of guilt? The answer is clear—' A cry of
>   torment broke from Robayday. He thrust out a hand as if physically to
>   intercept Kimon Euras's words.*
>
> *'Lies! Lies! **This is a room of lies.** I will speak the truth,
>   though it destroy me! I confess I did that thing to Simoda Tal. I did
>   it not because I was in league with my father the king. Oh, no, that's
>   impossible. We are day and night. I did what I did to spite him.*